# python syntax error on manage.py makemigrations

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, makemigrations

When I start python3 manage.py makemigration from *Django for everybody course lab Week 5 Django Features and Libraries* I get this error:

```
(django3) 12:01 ~/django_projects/mysite $ python3 manage.py makemigrations                                                                                                                                  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  ...
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/progroman/django_projects/mysite/mysite/settings.py", line 55
    CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

settings.py code below. If I comment CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3' syntax error point to TAGGIT_CASE_INSENSITIVE = True

```python3
import os
from pathlib import Path
    
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    
APP_NAME = 'ChucksList'
    
SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    
DEBUG = True
    
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
    
# Application definition
    
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    
    # Extensions - installed with pip3 / requirements.txt
    'django_extensions', 
    'crispy_forms',  
    'rest_framework', 
    'social_django',  
    'taggit',
    'home.apps.HomeConfig',
    'crispy.apps.CrispyConfig',
    
# Sample Applications - don't copy
# When we get to crispy forms :)
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'
    
# When we get to tagging
TAGGIT_CASE_INSENSITIVE = True
```

Please tell me what's wrong in settings.py

Comment: You forgot to end the list of your `INSTALLED_APPS`, a `]` is missing.

Comment: Thank you, your anwers is correct!